# What does FastCGI: comm with server mean?

Tags: php, apache, fastcgi

I'm getting this error in a PHP (Drupal) application:

```
(104)Connection reset by peer: FastCGI: comm with server "/opt/php-5.2.5/bin/php-cgi" aborted: read failed
```

It is often followed  by this error:

```
FastCGI: incomplete headers (0 bytes) received from server "/opt/php-5.2.5/bin/php-cgi"
```

The basic Apache configuration for PHP looks like this:

```
   FastCgiServer /opt/php-5.2.5/bin/php-cgi -initial-env PHP_FCGI_CHILDREN=32
   ScriptAlias /fcgi-bin/php-5.2.5 /opt/php-5.2.5/bin/php-cgi
   <Location /fcgi-bin/php-5.2.5>
     Options +ExecCGI
     SetHandler fastcgi-script
     SetOutputFilter INCLUDES
   </Location>
   # send php5.2-fastcgi handler to our scriptalias
   Action php-5.2.5-fastcgi /fcgi-bin/php-5.2.5
```

Now, my basic question is, what are the general causes of the "comm with server" error? In this particular case, the error appears intermittently, but certain pages generate it more often than others. I'd like to know what to look for when debugging my code.

Answer (score 4):

In this particular issue, it was related to an odd bug in my code... it seems certain kinds of errors cause FastCGI to fail so badly that it doesn't forward on the underlying PHP code error. Sorry I don't have more detail for those of you visiting from Google.

Answer (score 1):

What's the character set you're using?
I've read that some people is having issues if their app is using a different character set.

Look at [this](http://isearchthenet.com/forums/viewtopic.php?t=622&sid=a5628d8d15d84d5722819264622fd8fc)

Sorry I can't find better results.

Comment: Sorry mate, can't get a cached copy of this.

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes it helps.
`output.buffering = 1` into your php.ini file

Answer (score 0):

None of the above addressed my particular issue, there's a great answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18009479/random-php-fastcgi-connection-reset-by-peer-incomplete-headers) that did!

Answer (score -1):

I had the same problem but in python and i resolved changing the extention of my script to .py

```
#.htaccess file
AddHandler fastcgi-script .py
```